# Swift: How to use Timer to run func once a minute to prevent comment spam?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm trying to create a function to only allow users to send a message once every 60 seconds.

I thought a good way to do that might be using a timer in the `didSet` block of a bool variable that's keeping track of if a user could send a message, and reseting the bool back to false every 60 seconds. A user might try sending many messages within 60 seconds so it needs to work more than once, which is why I'm checking if a timer is already running.

How would you do this?

Here's my code that I think is close:

```
private var isTimerOn: Bool = false
private var isSending: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if !isTimerOn {
            let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true){ _ in
                self.isSending = false
                self.isTimerOn = true
             }
        }
    }
}

func sendMessage(){
    isSending = true
}
```

Comment: That's what the return result of `Timer.scheduledTimer()` is for, but with that `let _ = ` you explicitly opted to discard the result.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Sorry, so what would it be?

Comment: Oh I think I misread the question. I would change this so that you start the timer when a message is actually sent. With your current infinitely-repeating timer, you don't have a 60 lock out period, you have a 0-59.999 second lockout, depending on how far along the timer was at the time the user happened to post.

Comment: Although I would improve on this code by packaging up this "debouncing" logic to a seperate class, with methods like `didPost()` and `canPost()`, with the timer managed internally.

I would also change the `isTimerOn` boolean to a property of type `Timer?`, with `nil` indicating there's no currently running timer, and `non-nil` indicating there's a running timer. (just make sure to reset back to nil on upon firing).